# setw() does not affect reading integer fields

Tags: c++, stl

I wrote a code like this:

```
int d{ 0 };
cin >> setw(2) >> d;
```

But it seems `setw()` has no effect on reading integers. If so, how we could implement behaviour of `%2d` of `scanf()` with `istream`?

Comment: A bad idea does not imply a bad question. UV'd. This is well-posed IMHO.

Comment: maybe you should read a line, and truncate it

Comment: @Bathsheba Why that's a bad idea? I want to convert a hex string (think a UUID) to a byte array. I can do this by `sscanf()` but I want to know if **stl** support doing that with input streams?

Comment: See my answer. The C++ standards committee would have a lot of fun with this one: too many unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setw()` is not *designed* to be used with integral types.

What would it do? Extract the last two decimal digits of the integer? What would happen if you had put `std::hex` into the stream?

The best approach is to read the number then deal with it yourself. For example, if you want to extract the least significant two digits, use `d % 100` subsequently; making an extra correction for negative numbers.

Comment: Hmm, I interpreted the intent as reading the first two digits and leaving the rest in the stream.

Comment: That's fundamentally the issue: it's too ambiguous.

Comment: @aschepler You're write. That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @Bathsheba What ambiguity does you mean? In my question or in standard?

Comment: No your question's precise. What's not is the finer details of an implementation. Why don't you attempt to specify it yourself?

Comment: @Bathsheba I think there is no solution that's use pure **stl** (and that is strange). So I accept your solution as a *no solution*!

Comment: Actually I think you almost could: you could build your own integral type class with an overloaded << to istream: that could inspect the setw setting and act accordingly.

Comment: What it would do? Simple: It would behave exactly like `%2i` (or `%2x` for hex). It's regrettable that in 2020 the state of C++ I/O is such that nobody outside CS101 uses it.